# Cosine similarity between pair of arrays in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a table that has a pair of IDs and coordinate fro each of them so that I can calculate pairwise cosine similarity between them.

The table looks like this[image]

The number of dimension for the coords are currently 128, but it can vary. But the number dimensions for a pair of ID are always same in the same table.

`coord1` and `coord2` are repeated field (array) with floating point values.

Is there a way to calculate cosine similarity between them?

My expected output would have three columns, `id1`, `id2` and `cosine_similarity`.

Comment: Hi, i know its been 2 years already, still want to know how did you create such table?  did you create a json file or bigquery table? thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id1, id2, ( 
  SELECT 
    SUM(value1 * value2)/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value1 * value1))/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value2 * value2))
  FROM UNNEST(coord1) value1 WITH OFFSET pos1 
  JOIN UNNEST(coord2) value2 WITH OFFSET pos2 
  ON pos1 = pos2
  ) cosine_similarity
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

below is dummy example for you to play with

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id1, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] coord1, 2 id2, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] coord2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, [2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0], 4, [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
)
SELECT id1, id2, ( 
  SELECT 
    SUM(value1 * value2)/
    SQRT(SUM(value1 * value1))/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value2 * value2))
  FROM UNNEST(coord1) value1 WITH OFFSET pos1 
  JOIN UNNEST(coord2) value2 WITH OFFSET pos2 
  ON pos1 = pos2
  ) cosine_similarity
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row id1 id2 cosine_similarity    
1   1   2   1.0  
2   3   4   0.8215838362577491
```

Comment: Kudos for that extra dummy example!!