# Calculating pairwise cosine similarity between quite a large number of vectors in Bigquery

Tags: cosine-similarity, google-bigquery

I have a table `id_vectors` that contains `id` and their corresponding `coordinates`. Each of the `coordinates` is a repeated fields with 512 elements inside it.

I am looking for pairwise cosine similarity between all those vectors, e.g. If I have three `ids` 1,2 and 3 then I am looking for a table where I have cosine similarity between them (based on the calculation using 512 coordinates) like below:

```
id1   id2   similarity
 1     2      0.5
 1     3      0.1
 2     3      0.99
```

Now in my table I have 424,970 unique `ID` and their corresponding 512-dimension coordinates. Which means that basically I need to create around (424970 * 424969 / 2) unique pair of IDs and calculate their similarity.

I first tried with the following query using [reference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927630/cosine-similarity-between-pair-of-arrays-in-bigquery):

```
#standardSQL
with pairwise as
(SELECT t1.id as id_1, t1.coords as coord1, t2.id as id_2, t2.coords as coord2
FROM `project.dataset.id_vectors` t1
inner join `project.dataset.id_vectors` t2
on t1.id < t2.id)

SELECT id_1, id_2, ( 
  SELECT 
    SUM(value1 * value2)/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value1 * value1))/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value2 * value2))
  FROM UNNEST(coord1) value1 WITH OFFSET pos1 
  JOIN UNNEST(coord2) value2 WITH OFFSET pos2 
  ON pos1 = pos2
  ) cosine_similarity
FROM pairwise
```

But after running for 6 hrs I encountered the following error message 
`Query exceeded resource limits. 2.2127481953201417E7 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 428000.0 CPU seconds.`

Then I thought rather than using an intermediate table `pairwise`, why don't I try to create that table first then do the cosine similarity calculation.

So I tried the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id as id_1, t1.coords as coord1, t2.id as id_2, t2.coords as coord2
FROM `project.dataset.id_vectors` t1
inner join `project.dataset.id_vectors` t2
on t1.id < t2.id
```

But this time the query could not be completed and I encountered the following message:
`Error: Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for total shuffle size limit. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors`.

Then I tried to create even a smaller table, by just creating the combination pairs of the ids and stripping off the coordinates from it, using the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id as id_1, t2.id as id_2
FROM `project.dataset.id_vectors` t1
inner join `project.dataset.id_vectors` t2
on t1.id < t2.id
```

Again my query ends up with the error message `Query exceeded resource limits. 610104.3843576935 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 3000.0 CPU seconds. (error code: billingTierLimitExceeded)`

I totally understand that this is a huge query and my stopping point is my billing quota.

What I am asking is that, is there a way to execute the query in a smarter way so that I do not exceed either of the `resourceLimit`, `shuffleSizeLimit` or `billingTierLimit`?

Comment: sometimes knowing reason for doing expensive stuff - helps finding proper workaround by reducing amount of pairs to process (currently 90 billion pairs with 1K elements in each - quite a volume!). so what you do with those results (id1, id2, similarity)?

Comment: After the finding similarities, I intend to to keep the pairs with non-negative similairty, and later will try to create clusters based on those similarities. So if the the question is do I need all the pairwise similarities, then my answer is yes.

Comment: so final goal is to build clusters of ids?

Comment: yes. But on the way i need the similarity between all pairs.

Comment: sure, understood

Comment: did you have chance to try ideas in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Quick idea is - instead of joining table on itself with redundant coordinates - you should rather just create simple table of pairs (id1, id2), so then you will "dress" respective id's with their coordinates vectors by having two extra joining to `dataset.table.id_vectors`

Below is quick example of how this could looks like:

```
#standardSQL
WITH pairwise AS (
  SELECT t1.id AS id_1, t2.id AS id_2
  FROM `project.dataset.id_vectors` t1
  INNER JOIN `project.dataset.id_vectors` t2
  ON t1.id < t2.id
)
SELECT id_1, id_2, ( 
  SELECT 
    SUM(value1 * value2)/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value1 * value1))/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value2 * value2))
  FROM UNNEST(a.coords) value1 WITH OFFSET pos1 
  JOIN UNNEST(b.coords) value2 WITH OFFSET pos2 
  ON pos1 = pos2
  ) cosine_similarity
FROM pairwise t
JOIN `project.dataset.id_vectors` a ON a.id = id_1
JOIN `project.dataset.id_vectors` b ON b.id = id_2
```

Obviously it works on small dummy set as you can see below:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.id_vectors` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] coords UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, [2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0] UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, [0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0] UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5, [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0] UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
), pairwise AS (
  SELECT t1.id AS id_1, t2.id AS id_2
  FROM `project.dataset.id_vectors` t1
  INNER JOIN `project.dataset.id_vectors` t2
  ON t1.id < t2.id
)
SELECT id_1, id_2, ( 
  SELECT 
    SUM(value1 * value2)/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value1 * value1))/ 
    SQRT(SUM(value2 * value2))
  FROM UNNEST(a.coords) value1 WITH OFFSET pos1 
  JOIN UNNEST(b.coords) value2 WITH OFFSET pos2 
  ON pos1 = pos2
  ) cosine_similarity
FROM pairwise t
JOIN `project.dataset.id_vectors` a ON a.id = id_1
JOIN `project.dataset.id_vectors` b ON b.id = id_2
```

with result

```
Row id_1    id_2    cosine_similarity    
1   1       2       1.0  
2   1       3       0.6708203932499369   
3   1       4       0.819891591749923    
4   1       5       0.521749194749951    
5   1       6       0.9128709291752769   
6   2       3       0.6708203932499369   
7   2       4       0.819891591749923    
8   2       5       0.521749194749951    
9   2       6       0.9128709291752769   
10  3       4       0.3333333333333334   
11  3       5       0.8333333333333335   
12  3       6       0.8164965809277261   
13  4       5       0.5000000000000001   
14  4       6       0.8164965809277261   
15  5       6       0.8164965809277261
```

So, try on your real data and let's see how it will work for you :o)

And ... obviously you should pre-create / materialize `pairwise` table

Another optimization idea is to have pre-calculated values of `SQRT(SUM(value1 * value1))` in your `project.dataset.id_vectors` - this can save quite CPU - this should be simple adjustment so I leave it to you :o)

Comment: I have already tried your first idea, it stopped after three hours,  with error `Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for total shuffle size limit.`

Comment: Now I just started with a precalculated sqrt_sum_of_sqr table, lets see what happens.

Comment: But if you look at my question, I wasn't even able to have a pre-created `pairwise` table, I exceeded the `shuffleSizeLimit` over that simple table creation

Comment: when I said materialize `pairwise` table - i meant my version of that table (just pairs of id1 and id2) - it still can have that issue but worse trying  - just wanted to clarify!

Comment: so, please clarify - where you able to create / materialize `pairwise` table based on version in my answer? as you can see from answer  - it is quite different from the table you tried to persist - because it has just pair of ids - so we have good chance to not exceed shuffleSizeLimit!

Comment: I think your version of pairwise creation query and my version (my final try in the question) is the same. I already tried that and failed.

Comment: But I just started your version of pairwise creation query just now, just to make sure.

Comment: My version selects ONLY id_1 and id_2. Your version selects id_1, coord1, id_2, coord2 - this is HUGE difference and is an important part of idea i explained in my answer!

Comment: Look at this part in my question, "Then I tried to create even a smaller table....Query exceeded resource limits. 610104.3843576935 CPU seconds were used......", I have already tried that.

Comment: Yayk! I totally missed this part! :o(

Comment: Right, that frustrated me the most! It should be a simple table, not too large, but Bigquery fails at creating that. Actually it requires different billing tier for that..

Comment: Ok. I think you should "extract" this particular issue out of you final similarity related stuff and post separate question just for how to create such a table - I think in such case you will have better chances to proper get answer on that particular issue. meantime - i will think of it no matter what - but really recommend posting separate question!

Comment: A separate question on how to create a LARGE pairwise table?

Comment: yes, i think this new question should be very focused on issue of creating very big pairwise table - strip out everything else that is not related to this - after you will address that issue  - you then hopefully will get back to this one and see if your final goal is achievable here