# Creating pairwise combination of ids of a very large table in bigquery

Tags: combinations, google-bigquery

I have a very large table of ids (string) that has 424,970 rows and only a single column.

I am trying to create the combination of those ids in a new table. The motivation for creation of that table can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953848/calculating-pairwise-cosine-similarity-between-quite-a-large-number-of-vectors-i).

I tried the following query to create the pairwise combination table:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  t1.id AS id_1,
  t2.id AS id_2
FROM
  `project.dataset.id_vectors` t1
INNER JOIN
  `project.dataset.id_vectors` t2
ON
  t1.id < t2.id
```

But the query fails after 15 minutes, with the following error message:

`Query exceeded resource limits. 602467.2409093559 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 3000.0 CPU seconds. (error code: billingTierLimitExceeded)`

Is there any workaround to run the query and get the desired output table with all combination of ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try splitting your table T into 2 smaller tables T1 and T2, then perform 4 joins for each of the smaller tables T1:T1, T1:T2, T2:T1, T2:T2, then union the results. This will be equivalent to joining T with itself. If it still fails try breaking it down into even smaller tables.

Alternatively set `maximumBillingTier` to a higher value https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs.

> configuration.query.maximumBillingTier - Limits the billing tier for
>   this job. Queries that have resource usage beyond this tier will fail
>   (without incurring a charge). If unspecified, this will be set to your
>   project default.

If using Java, it can be set in [`JobQueryConfiguration`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/QueryJobConfiguration.java#L480). This configuration property is not supported in the UI console at the moment.

---

In order to split a table you can use [FARM_FINGERPRINT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions#farm_fingerprint) function in BigQuery. E.g. the 1st part will have a filter:

```
where mod(abs(farm_fingerprint(id)), 10) < 5
```

And the 2nd part will the filter:

```
where mod(abs(farm_fingerprint(id)), 10) >= 5
```